# Create variable/column equal to another column/factor frequency

Tags: r

**The Short**

I have

```
X <- data.frame(Animal = c("Ant", "Cat", "Dog", "Ant", "Dog", "Ant", "Ant"))
```

and I want to create add a column `freq` to `X` such that

```
> X
  Animal Freq
1    Ant    4
2    Cat    1
3    Dog    2
4    Ant    4
5    Dog    2
6    Ant    4
7    Ant    4
```

**The Long**

I have

```
> X <- data.frame(Animal = c("Ant", "Cat", "Dog", "Ant", "Dog", "Ant", "Ant"))
> X
  Animal
1    Ant
2    Cat
3    Dog
4    Ant
5    Dog
6    Ant
7    Ant
```

I know that

```
> table(X)
X
Ant Cat Dog 
  4   1   2
```

Or

```
> count(X)
  Animal freq
1    Ant    4
2    Cat    1
3    Dog    2
```

and that

```
> subset(count(X), Animal == "Ant")$freq
[1] 4
```

and even that

```
> subset(count(X), Animal == X[1,1])$freq
[1] 4
> subset(count(X), Animal == X[2,1])$freq
[1] 1
```

but I'm struggling to put all together to add a column `freq` to `X` such that

```
> X
  Animal Freq
1    Ant    4
2    Cat    1
3    Dog    2
4    Ant    4
5    Dog    2
6    Ant    4
7    Ant    4
```

I suspect that the recommendation will be use apply in some way but I can't even get the function to work properly. I can get the following to work

```
> fn.freq <- function(FreqTable, Variable){
+   return(subset(FreqTable, Animal == Variable)$freq)
+ }
> fn.freq(count(X),X[1,1])
[1]
```

But this still has `Animal` hard coded into the function when I really want it to be dynamic/a function variable but all my attempts at that fail miserably.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: with `dplyr` you can achieve the goal with `X %>% group_by(Animal) %>% mutate(freq = n())` but I am sure there is an elegant solution in base R too. Most likely this question is a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ave`:

```
X <- transform(X, freq = ave(as.integer(Animal), Animal, FUN = length))

#   Animal freq
# 1    Ant    4
# 2    Cat    1
# 3    Dog    2
# 4    Ant    4
# 5    Dog    2
# 6    Ant    4
# 7    Ant    4
```

Answer (score 2):

As my previous comment: A simple and easy solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
X %>% group_by(Animal) %>% mutate(freq = n())

Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
Groups: Animal

  Animal freq
1    Ant    4
2    Cat    1
3    Dog    2
4    Ant    4
5    Dog    2
6    Ant    4
7    Ant    4
```

#### Edit: explanation

The `%>%` is a "pipe operator", It is been developed in the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package and works like this `f(x)` is the same as `x %>% f()` (where `f` is an R function like `mean` or like `mutate` and so on... just an R function).
It is just a tool for a more concise and easy to read code, often just a personal choice. It is used by dplyr but you can use with other packages and base R as well.

My code does a simply two things: 1) it split the data in different groups each one for every `Animal`, after that it creates (with `Mutate`) a new column called `freq` that just use the `n()` function (implemented in `dplyr`) that essentially counts the elements of each group.

Comment: Thanks SabDeM that definitely does the trick. After looking up dplyr (very nice library) and mutate I'm still not sure what your line actually does. Any chance you have the time to explain? I always thought that %*% etc were matrix related operators.

Comment: @SC. I have updated the answer, I hope that my code is now more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions:

```
merge(X, table(X$Animal), by.x = "Animal", by.y = "Var1")

# In descending order by frequency
  Animal Freq
1    Ant    4
2    Ant    4
3    Ant    4
4    Ant    4
5    Cat    1
6    Dog    2
7    Dog    2
```

Using sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM X
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT Animal, COUNT(*) AS Freq FROM X GROUP BY Animal)
      USING (Animal)")

  Animal Freq
1    Ant    4
2    Cat    1
3    Dog    2
4    Ant    4
5    Dog    2
6    Ant    4
7    Ant    4
```